# datatables - nested table height style

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

I have created nested tables for extra infomation following the datatables example above. I have created two tables similar to the one in the example. I'm now trying to set the height of these tables to a fixed amount and enable scrolling so the little tables can be scrolled if lots of infomation is present.

I added this to the dataTables.css:

```
table.dataTable table
{
  //all of these work
  width: 47%;
  margin:1%;
  float:left;
  border: solid 1px #dddddd;

  // none of these take affect
  min-height: 50px !important;
  max-height: 50px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The browser inspector displays all the css correctly on the tables, just ignores height/scroll for some unknown reason, I'm unusre why half the styles are working.

- How else can I set the height of the nested tables?

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

You can wrap your child rows in a `<div class="child-container></div>` in `format()` JavaScript function and apply the following CSS rules:

```css
table.dataTable .child-container {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table.dataTable .child-container table {
  width: 47%;
  margin:10px 10px 10px 40px;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #DDD;
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2j2gbrfp/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks..This kinda works like i needed, was trying to get the nested tables `<tbody>` to be the fixed height tho. I'm not sure why I couldnt set height on the table elements tho?